# Find multiple '/' forward slashes in string of URLs for sitemap

Tags: regex, url, sitemap

We are trying to clean up our site map as our Magento store has created duplicate pages. I want to use a regular expression to select, or invert select, all of the pages which are linked to the top level URL.

For example, we want to find the first line-

`/site/product`<<

`/site/category/product/`

`/site/category/product`

Is there any way to find only two instances of a forward slash in the whole string, which are not next to each other?

Thank you for your help in advance.

I've tried something like this

`(.*(?<!\/)$)`

Comment: In which language are you working? I suspect the simplest way is to extract _all_ sub-domains at once via `regex` and then remove the duplicates (using a language of your choosing).

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `(.*(?<!\/)$)` matches any char except a newline until the end of the string and after that asserts that what is on the left is not a forward slash which will give you the first and the third match.

You could match from the start of the string `^` 2 times a forward slash and then 1+ times not a forward slash  or a newline `[^/\n]+` and then assert the end of the string `$`

```
^/[^/\n]+/[^/\n]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LdWUyA/1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the end, we used Notepad ++ to bookmark the category URLs and removed them manually. It's just a temp fix until we replace the website.

Comment: @ninjutsuju Did my answer help you solving it?

Comment: I'm afraid not as it didn't work straight away, but if we were still going down the regex route I'm sure your answer would have only required some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

I would like like to provide a quick answer to this problem in case it helps anyone else in the future. Our sitemap had too many duplicate URLs due to an incorrect set up on our Magento store. Instead of submitting a sitemap with 20,000+ top-level URLs we decided to manually remove the top level items ourselves.

Not ideal at all.

We tweaked with the site map PHP generation code to pull top-level URLs as site/category/id/###. Then we used Notepad++ to bookmark and delete these lines accordingly.